# Compojure multiple contexts

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have a `defroutes` like:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (context "first" []
    (GET "/" [] "first first"))
  (context "second" []
    (GET "/" [] "first second")))
```

But when I try to visit `/second` I just get a 404. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Minor, but important detail: you are missing leading slashes on the context declarations, so for example "/first", not "first".

```clj
(defroutes app-routes
  (context "/first" []
    (GET "/" [] "first first"))
  (context "second" []
    (GET "/" [] "first second")))
```